# How to play animations in a SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, animation, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView which is currently drawing a series of Bitmaps. These bitmaps can easily be manipulated geometrically (scale/rotate/translate/etc). An example would be a ball which is bouncing, which may just use translate/rotate operations. The ball is just a single bitmap.

I wish to replace this 'ball' Bitmap with a sequence of Bitmaps, for example if the ball were to explode in a flurry of fireworks, I have the individual frames and I wish to string them together.

Without having to manually cycle through them on each onDraw() call in my SurfaceView, how can I go about this? I know in normal conditions I can just make an AnimationDrawable using the frames in an XML file, bind it to an ImageView (set as background) then call it. However, I am using a SurfaceView for displaying all my graphics on screen, not ImageViews. I have read you can overlay other views on top of SurfaceViews, but I am unsure that I could get the exact position required. For example, the ball may explode at X=65 Y=21 on my SurfaceView, how could I translate this exact co-ordinate to my ImageView?

Any help or tips on alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it more separated, you can create another class that handles this animation and keeps track of which frame it's on and the bitmaps to use then delegate drawing of the sprite to this class in your `SurfaceView`'s `onDraw`.

Comment: This is probably the method I'm going to have to use unless there is some convenient method that I'm missing, which I hope someone may know.

Comment: Three is no need to keep track of anything of the kind.  You can use an AnimationDrawable.  See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531246/android-animate-character-in-surfaceview