# Android animate character in SurfaceView

Tags: android, animation, surfaceview

I want to animate a character (for eg run a dog) on screen. AnimationDrawable seemed a perfect fit for this, and AnimationDrawable requires an ImageView. How do I add and move around the ImageView in SurfaceView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need an `ImageView`.

If your animation is an `XML Drawable`, you can load it directly from the `Resources` into an `AnimationDrawable` variable:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.anim);
```

Then set it's bounds and draw on the canvas:

```
animation.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
animation.draw(canvas);
```

You also need to manually set the animation to run on it's next scheduled interval. This can be accomplished by creating a new Callback using `animation.setCallback`, then instantiating an `android.os.Handler` and using the `handler.postAtTime` method to add the next animation frame to the current `Thread`'s message queue.

```
animation.setCallback(new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
    return;
  }

  @Override
  public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
    //Schedules a message to be posted to the thread that contains the animation
    //at the next interval. 
    //Required for the animation to run. 
    Handler h = new Handler(); 
    h.postAtTime(what, when);
  }

  @Override
  public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
    return;
  }
});

animation.start();
```

Comment: Is there  a reason you don't reuse the Handler?

Answer (score 0):

With a SurfaceView it is your responsibility to draw everything within it. You do not need AnimationDrawable or any view to render your character on it. Take a look onto [Lunar Lander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) example game from Google.

Comment: Thanks Burov, so AnimationDrawable is not suited for games?

Comment: Yes it is.  AnimationDrawable isn't a view and you CAN use it as explained by nmelo.