# How to place AnimationDrawable on a SurfaceView canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

Noob to game development and I'm having trouble placing an AnimationDrawable onto a SurfaceView canvas. It's part of a simple game, user touches screen and an animated gif is placed at that location that looks like an explosion. I can accomplish this with a Bitmap using the code shown below, but converting this to an AnimationDrawable is where I'm stuck. I could create the AnimationDrawable from an ImageView, but I can't find a way to get the ImageView onto the canvas either...

Am I going about this in the wrong way? Is there a simpler way to get an animated gif to display at an x,y coordinate on a SurfaceView's canvas?

```
Bitmap explodeBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explode4);
canvas.drawBitmap(explodeBmp, coords.getX()-(explodeBmp.getWidth()/2), coords.getY()-(explodeBmp.getHeight()/2), paint);
```

This throws a ClassCastException if I try to convert the Bitmap to an AnimationDrawable and start it:

```
AnimationDrawable explosionAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ((Drawable) new BitmapDrawable(explodeBmp));
explosionAnimation.start();
```

Comment: anyone have at least a hint? comment? lead in the right direction? any game developers out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After continuous digging I've found the answer... seems I like answering my own questions here.

Just found the Movie class. I can load my animated gif into it using an InputStream, then play the movie bit by bit in my onDraw() because the Movie class supports a draw() method where I can supply my canvas and x,y coordinates.

Here's the code snippit below:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.dotz_explosion);
Movie explodeGif = Movie.decodeStream(is);

...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
      GraphicObject explosion = (GraphicObject)ex.next();

      long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
      if (explosion.getMovieStart() == 0) { // first time
         explosion.setMovieStart(now);
      }

      int relTime = (int)((now - explosion.getMovieStart()) % explodeGif.duration());
      if ((now - explosion.getMovieStart()) >= explodeGif.duration()) {
         removeArrayExplosions.add(removeIndex);
         explosion.setMovieStart(0);
      } else {
         explodeGif.setTime(relTime);
         explodeGif.draw(canvas, explosion.getX()-(explodeGif.width()/2), explosion.getY()-(explodeGif.height()/2));
      }
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Using gifs are not recommended : positively discouraged. You should use an animation-list defined in XML. Using Movie would be hugely expensive. For people googling this  up now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531246/android-animate-character-in-surfaceview

Comment: @RichieHH hugely expensive as in memory usage? I have a couple old droids that I tried my app on and I could not see any performance issues. I've had dozens of movies simultaneously playing with no issue.

Comment: On the contrary using animation list is expensive in my experience. Every piece in the list will generate an isolate bitmap which costs large memory usage.